# Setup VPS with a Symfony2 project from git repository

Tags: symfony, vps

I have a:
- VPS with LAMP stack
- local symfony2 project (git)
- bitbucket repository

What do I need to do to properly setup my project in the production evironment?

Folder structure/permissions?
Can I simply clone the repository in the public folder? (I don't think so)

P.s. I've already read the deployment guide on the symfony2 website, but I didn't find it very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my deployment steps:

1. git clone project
2. go to project directory
3. php composer.phar install (and if composer is not in the project
   directory curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php)
4. app/console doctrine:database:create
5. app/console schema:update --force
6. app/console assets:install web --symlink
7. chmod 777 -R app/cache app/logs web/media/cache (I often use liip
   imagine, it resizes photo in web/media/cache)
8. point the virtual host of apache to the web directory of my project.
   And you are done.

you might want to enable mode rewrite in apach (a2enmod rewrite) I think this covers everything.

Comment: In a tutorial about "symfony setup on shared hosting" there were some steps to ensure that the app core files were not accessible to everyone (think about the parameters.yml or config.yml etc etc). Of course my question is about VPS (not shared hosting) BUT the concept may still be valid: do I need to do something to "protect" the application/controllers/core files of my project?

Comment: There is an htaccess written by symfony inside those folders that prevents users from being to access the directory, they will get a "forbidden" page. So you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Any advice about a nice and easy guide for Bitbucket post-hooks (for auto deployment)?

Comment: No sorry. I use a private gitlab, and even there I did not bother with hooks. I wrote bashscripts to auto deploy. Very simple, you just give the bashscripts the commands you usually use in succession and put them inside a method, and then you can trigger that method remotely, and it will deploy, update doctrine and install assets etc...I am not an expert on scripts but it worked very nicely for me.